# Pull out certain nested objects

Tags: javascript

I have a series of nested objects like this:

```
data = {"12345":{"value":{"1":"2","3":"4"}},
   {"12346":{"value":{"5":"6","7":"8"}},
   {"12347":{"value":{"9":"0","11":"22"}}
```

I would like to create a function to grab certain objects within this grouping. For example...

```
grabObject(12345);
```

would return:

```
{"value":{"1":"2","3":"4"}}
```

Any help you could provide would be great.

Comment: You should show what you've tried. If you've not tried anything, you should make an attempt to implement what you need. As it stands, we don't know if you don't know how to create a function, how to return a value, or how to get a value from an object. Your question doesn't have a clear problem statement.

Comment: ...and your object syntax is invalid, so it's really not clear what you need anyway.

Comment: jriend00 answered my question, thank you.  And I actually do know how to write a function, i'm not quite that bad at javascript! ;)

Comment: @JustinTerrell If you feel that jfriend00 has answered your question then it is highly recommended that you select his answer.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. I corrected your syntax and wrote the answer please check and let me know if anything wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything more than this:

```
function grabObject(id) {
    return data[id];
}
```

After making some fixes to your syntax, here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/04no0bvm/

Comment: That was way simpler then I thought, thank you still new to javascript.  Much appreciated!

Comment: I think this is not right answer. As the syntax provided by questioner is wrong either or may be his explanation is wrong

Comment: @murli2308 - The OP's question is missing only a single closing brace.  That's no reason for you to change their data into an entirely different data structure and then invent an answer for that new structure.

Comment: @JustinTerrell - Since it looks like you may be new here, are you aware that if your question is answered, then you can indicate that to the community here by clicking on the green checkmark next to the best answer.  This will reward the person who provided the answer and also earn you some reputation points which will earn you more privileges here over time.

Comment: Thank you jfriend, i am new here and i appreciate your patience as i am also new to javascript but am pretty well versed in php and yes my structure was missing a closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
{
    "12345": {
        "value": {
            "1": "2",
            "3": "4"
        }
    }
},
{
    "12346": {
        "value": {
            "5": "6",
            "7": "8"
        }
    }
},
{
    "12347": {
        "value": {
            "9": "0",
            "11": "22"
        }
    }
}
];


function grabObject(id) {
   var result;
   for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       for (var k in data[i]){
         if(k == id) {
           result = data[i][k];
         }
       }
   }
   return result;
}
console.log(grabObject('12345'));
```

This is the code I tested check and let me know

Comment: You changed the OP's data structure and made it into something that it is not.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you give fiddle of your answer? your answer is right when each object is different. Otherwise his syntax is wrong..

Comment: I added a jsFiddle to my answer.